# Twilio Direct Messaging Channel Names between two people?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to make a Chat application which uses direct messaging between two users using Twilio Programmable Chat API. I am using the JS SDK. My problem is that I am not able to understand how to assign a channel name for Direct Messaging between two people so that at either end the person is aware of the channel association. I am not able to understand how to maintain the channel names so that I don't encounter a situation where I have n! channels, an association of 1 to many. Please help.

I am using the code below for the private channels.

```
// Create a Channel
messagingClient.createChannel({
uniqueName: 'general',
friendlyName: 'General Chat Channel',
isPrivate: true
}).then(function(channel) {
console.log('Created general channel:');
console.log(channel);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are looking for a way to uniquely name the private channels between two users, then why not concatenate the identity's of the two users in your system.

Imagining that you are trying to create a channel for `userA` and `userB` and they both have an `id`. Then create the unique channel name by sorting the ids and concatenating:

```
function generateChannelName(userA, userB) {
  return [userA.id, userB.id].sort().join('-');
}
```

That way the channel name between two users will always be calculable and unique.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: You made my day. The solution was so simple and I was hunting all around.  Thanks a lot. I do have another question which I will post separately. It's about the data flashing when I ask for UniqueName of a channel. Your helps is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I will be looking out for your question (or any tagged "twilio" :) )